# dynamic web project creation option in eclipse helios

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.6, helios

I have installed eclipse helios from zip file with name 'eclipse-java-helios-SR1-win32' which means it is for win32 and SR1. But, after extracting these files and opening eclipse IDE I cannot create a dynamic web project from New->I cant find dynamic web project option.

Can anyone help me on this ?
Do I have to install any eclipse plugin for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should have gotten the eclipse-**javaee**-helios-SR1-win32 zip, or preferably the Indigo SR1 version  You can also search the Help|Install New Software option for features related to Java EE.